# How do you properly filter out a custom post type with unique categories in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How do you properly filter out a custom post type with unique categories in 
   WordPress?

when i am doing show the result: 
   Repeat value 
   1.HEALTH
   2.Education
   3.HEALTH

```
<?php
 global $post;
 $myposts = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'numberposts' => '999',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC'
 ));

?>
<ul>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post){ ?>                    
<li>
<a href="#">
<?php the_field("product_category")?>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```html
<?php
$myposts = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'numberposts' => '-1',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'
 ));

?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($myposts as $post){ ?>                    
<li>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

> **Notes:** 'posts_per_page' => -1, Add this to the WP_QUERY array of arguments and it should return all of the posts of this custom post
>   type.

Comment: if  am select HEALTH category two post that times health category repeat